# 2-Wasserstein barycenter of uniform distribution on ellipsoid

Tags: probability, measure-theory, optimal-transport, wasserstein

Let $A$ be a positive-definite symmetric matrix. Consider the ellipsoid $E = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon <x A^{-1} x> \leq 1 \}$.

Now consider uniform distribution $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n$ on $E_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon <x A_n^{-1} x> \leq 1 \}$. (for $1 \leq i \leq n$, $\mu_i$ uniform on $E_i$.)

What's the 2-Wasserstein barycenter of $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n$?

(where $W_2(\mu_1, \mu_2)^2 = \inf_{\pi \in \Gamma(\mu_1, \mu_2)} \int d(x,y)^2d \pi(x,y)$, and the barycenter is the measure that minimizes the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n W_2(\nu, \mu_i)^2$ )

Thanks!

It seems like it should be some uniform distribution on an ellipsoid, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: But if $\mu_{i}$ and $\mu_{j}$ are both uniform on $E_{n}$, then $W(\nu,\mu_{i})=W(\nu ,\mu_{j})$, no?

Comment: @Tobsn $\mu_i$ and $\mu_j$ are uniform on different $E_i$ and $E_j$ no?

Comment: So you want the barycenter of measures uniform on $n$ different ellpsoids? Then you should better write: for $1\le i \le n$ $\mu_{i}$ is uniform on $E_{i}$.

Comment: @Tobsn edited thanks

Comment: Is the barycenter of $n$ measures the same as the barycenter of one of them and the barycenter of the n-1 others?

Comment: @Tobsn oh are you suggesting induction?

Comment: Well, depends on the answer to my previous question. I don't know whether that's true.

Comment: @Tobsn what was your previous question? I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: D'oh. Is the barycenter of n measures the same as the barycenter of one of them and the barycenter of the n-1 others?

Comment: @Tobsn no all different